# ATK Radio Buttons with a model field

Tags: php, frameworks, atk4

How can I define radio buttons for a model field.

```
class Model_Campaign extends Model_Table {
  public $entity_code = 'campaign';
  function init() {
    parent::init();

    $this->addField('nombres')->mandatory(TRUE);
    $this->addField('email')->mandatory(TRUE);
    $this->addField('celular')->mandatory(TRUE);
    $this->addField('ciudad');
    $this->addField('operador')->mandatory(TRUE);
  }
}
```

I want to 'operador' field shows like radiobuttons, and I want to 'celular' field only accepts numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1# about radiobuttons

So, if you want to have radio buttons, this implies that either you have static list of values or you are referencing other model, thus do following:

a: `$this->hasOne("Operador", "operador")`, given you have Model_Operador
b: `$this->addField("operador")->datatype("list")->listData(array());`

this will make drop down to appear. If you want to have radio buttons:
add `->display("radio");`

2# validation - read documentation: http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/form/validation

```
->validateField('filter_var($this->get(), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)');
```

e.g.

```
$this->addField("fieldx")->validateField('filter_var($this->get(), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)');
```

n.b. make sure you use atk4.2 (master branch in github)

more filters: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: Thank you jancha, but how can I define the validator in the model?

`$this->addField('email')->mandatory(TRUE)
->validateField('filter_var($this->get(), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)');`

doesn't work

Comment: just add that validateField() into the model init block for the field that needs the validation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->addRadioAttribute("gender",array("male","female"));
```

here: `gender` is a **field name**, `male` and `female` **are values**.